# Xcode Ui-automation - Test not running on physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Is there any specific configuration if I want to run a test on a physical device?

-my physical device is running ios 9.0

-I have a provisioned profile (the app is running on the device)

-I already enabled UI automation (settings->developer)

-My active scheme is my target, and I selected the physical device

But when I run a test (UI test), there is a message "test succeeded " (nothing happens on the device, the app doesn't open at all, there is no error messages at all), and when I go to the report navigator, there is no info related with the test, that I just run.

if I run this test on the simulator it will run without problem.
Seems like xcode is not running the test at all, but it's showing the "test succeeded" message
Thanks !

Answer (score 9):

It seems like there are various reasons why this "Test Succeeded" message can occur. In my case, if I open the Mac OS X Console program, I see:

> 12/25/15 10:46:51.940 AM Xcode[42471]: _connect_to_port (thread
>   0x7000004ac000): USBMuxConnectByPort failed to connect to the device
>   [snip] on port 43234: Connection refused

Experiments:

a) Unplugging the device from the USB cable, and plugging it in: No effect.

b) Restart Xcode and remove Derived Data: No effect.

c) Restart the device (iPhone in this case): **That worked!**

Answer (score 0):

The provision profile needs to be correct, I just added an updated provisioned profile and it worked